# Only write my own messages in the log pyspark

Tags: python, logging, pyspark

I would like to export at the end of each run of a script a log file with only my printing statements while using Pyspark.

So far I managed to log my print statement into a log4j that I can export to S3 using the logging parameter in the cluster specifying the log export path (in the cluster configuration) and using the code below. However, I also get a lot of extra messages which I am not interested in. Using:

```
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
LOGGER.info("pyspark script logger initialized")
```

I get:

```
20/07/06 09:45:37 INFO DriverCorral: DBFS health check ok
20/07/06 09:45:49 INFO DriverCorral: Metastore health check ok
20/07/06 09:46:05 INFO ProgressReporter$: Added result fetcher for ...
20/07/06 09:46:05 INFO __main__: pyspark script logger initialized
20/07/06 09:46:05 INFO ProgressReporter$: Removed result fetcher for ...
```

Essentially, I would only like to print in my log:

```
20/07/06 09:46:05 INFO __main__: pyspark script logger initialized
```

Comment: Not sure if that can be done but you can try to set the log level to WARN and print your messages at WARN level where apart from your messages only warnings will be displayed.

Comment: You can try to disable the loggers that you don't want. something like this: `dc_logger = getLogger('DriverCorral') dc_logger.disabled = true`

Comment: Can you please check with the below python logger module ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with Python Logger module as below

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('pyspark script logger initialized.')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even though the code above runs fine, no message appears in the log of the driver. This package is probably not made to work on a spark cluster.